# Find out which child element I just clicked

Tags: javascript

I'd like to find the number of the clicked element in the `<li>` container. (e.g. The clicked element was the 3rd child.)

So far I have this code:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var dropDown = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[3];
    dropDown.addEventListener('click', hide, false);
    function hide(e) {
        // Find out the number of the n-th child element you clicked instead of hiding it
        e.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Is there a way to find out which child I clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might misunderstand, but isn't this what `indexOf()` does?

```
var els = el.parentNode.children; // or .childNodes if you want TextNodes
return [].indexOf.call(els, el);
```

So in an event handler:

```
function(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  var els = el.parentNode.children; // or .childNodes if you want TextNodes
  return [].indexOf.call(els, el);
}
```

Since `parentNode.children`/`parentNode.childNodes` doesn't return an `Array`, but a `NodeList` (or alike), the `indexOf()` method isn't available. Two fixes for that:

1. First create an `Array` from the `NodeList` and then call `indexOf`: `arr = [].slice.call(children)` which means: `Array.prototype.slice.call(children, 0)` which calls `Array`'s `slice()` method with a different `this` context (if you don't know what that means, read up on call/apply/this). And then: `arr.indexOf(el)`
2. Or use the same trick immediately on the NodeList. If `slice` works, `indexOf` should work too: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(children, el)` or shorter: `[].indexOf.call(children /*this*/, el /*arg1*/)`
3. My fav: `HTMLCollection.prototype.indexOf = NodeList.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf` et voila, now you **can** call `indexOf` directly on `children`. This is very much frowned upon though: extending native objects is apparently *A Bad Thing(TM)*.

All that is magic if you don't know how `this` works in JS (like magic!) and how `Function.prototype.call()` works.

Comment: works great. Could you explain a little bit about how the last line works. Im not familiar with the syntax nor the call function.

Comment: I've extended the answer with some explanation. Can't do much more. Great JS tutorials on `this/call/apply` on the interwebs.

Comment: I've added a # 3, my personal fav.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Something like this:

```
function whereami(elem) {
    var par = elem.parentNode, sibs = par.children, l = sibs.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( sibs[i] === elem) return i;
    }
    throw "I am invisible!";
}
```

Comment: do you have to do that? I mean this method is gonna loop through the list every time a click happens. This is a classic closure example I would suggest to use closure for the event handler method and that should work fine.

Comment: You can just shove it in a function.

Comment: @Sushil I think this would go into the `hide(e)` fn that the OP had in their snippet.

Comment: yes but still think about it, an element is clicked the method hide is called and it loops through the list to find out the element and give the index in return. There are two ways of solving this problem that i can think of on top of my head.

1. get the collection of HTMLLIElement assign them data-index attribute while looping and give the value as the index of that item.

2. Use closure something for the handler.

Comment: @Sushil There, happy now?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Alright somehow it still doesnt work for me. I copy paste your function right below my hide(e) function. then i call if from inside of hide function: `var index = whereami(e);alert(index);` It just breaks my javascript (alert doesn't show up)

Comment: still not getting my point, here's the example 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LS6nw/)

Comment: @Xitcod13 You should pass `this`, not `e`.

Answer (score 0):

This does as few iterations as possible, but this seems to be the only way to do this without using a library like jQuery.

```
function count_element(elem) {
    var x = elem.previousSibling;
    var n = 0;

    while (x.nodeType!=1) {
      x = x.previousSibling;
      n++;
    }

    return n;
}
```